# const char * pointing to same memory location

Tags: c++

I am trying to break a string into integer and characters using below codes. in the first section on the immediate printing I got the right output but later it is wrong.

```
int Lottery::calcInvOdds(string ruleConstraint){
const char * sorted;
const char * unique;
string temp;
size_t pos;

temp = ruleConstraint;

pos = temp.find_first_of(" ");
sorted = temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();
cout << temp << endl;
cout << "S = " << sorted << endl;

 temp = temp.substr(pos+1);
 unique = temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();
 cout << "U = " << unique << endl;

cout << "Sorted = " << sorted[0] << " " << "Unique = " << unique[0] << endl<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Output is like this:

```
T F
S = T
U = F
Sorted = F Unique = F

F T
S = F
U = T
Sorted = T Unique = T
```

But after replacing `const char *` with array like `char sorted[2]` and `temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();` with `*temp.substr(0,pos).c_str()`, Correct output was displayed. What is the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: The string that came back from `sorted = temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();` ? Yeah, its gone as soon as that semi-colon is hit. The resulting pointer is indeterminate and dereferencing it invokes undefined behavior. The same goes for `unique = temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sorted = temp.substr(0,pos).c_str();
```

This isn't going to work. `temp.substr(0,pos)` returns a temporary `string`, `.c_str()` gets a pointer to its contents, and after the statement completes the temporary `string` is freed, making `sorted` point to freed memory.

Your best option is to not even bother converting to `const char*` and instead change `sorted` and `unique` to be `string`s. Then things will work like you expect, because the strings will persist until the function exits.

```
int Lottery::calcInvOdds(const string& ruleConstraint){
    size_t pos = ruleConstraint.find_first_of(" ");
    string sorted = ruleConstraint.substr(0, pos);
    // The above line could be rewritten as:
    // string sorted(ruleConstraint, 0, pos);

    cout << ruleConstraint << endl;
    cout << "S = " << sorted << endl;

    // -- Not sure this is  what you want, but it's what your code does.
    #if 1
    string unique = ruleConstraint.substr(pos + 1, pos);

    // -- maybe you meant this
    #else
    size_t pos2 = ruleConstraint.find_first_of(" ", pos + 1);
    string unique(ruleConstraint, pos + 1, pos2 - pos - 1);
    #endif

    cout << "U = " << unique << endl;

    cout << "Sorted = " << sorted[0] << " " << "Unique = " << unique[0] << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```